# How do I change the Wagtail Admin Dashboard Title from "Welcome to the bakerydemo Wagtail CMS"?

Tags: wagtail

I can't figure out how to change the Admin Dashboard Title from "Welcome to the bakerydemo Wagtail CMS". Does anyone know how?

Comment: Search for this string in the software source code ?

Answer (score 5):

The "bakerydemo" name is defined as `WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME` in `settings/base.py` - you can change that setting to change the site name displayed.

To replace the message entirely, create a template `wagtailadmin/home.html` in one of your apps which overrides the block `{% block branding_welcome %}`. See http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html for full instructions.

Answer (score 1):

you can override by following this steps.

1. make sure you have included 'wagtail.admin' in installed apps
2. create a wagtailadmin folder inside of your templates folder
3. create a page home.html inside your wagtailadmin folder
4. In home.html you can override now welcome branding by below code

```html
    {% extends "wagtailadmin/home.html" %}

    {% block branding_welcome %}Welcome to my page {% endblock %}
```